# Show data on enter or tab in a datagridvied vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have problems when I do the following process.

When I type in a cell of the following datagridview and when pressing tab or enter, the record I am looking for is not displayed.

I have the following code that repeats what I am looking for and 1 automatic row is added when pressing enter.

```
Sub mostrarproductosbonus()

    dt = negLog.buscar_pro_parametro(VGlobales.Base, Me.dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)

    For Each data As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim aa As Integer = Me.dgvdetalle.Rows.Add()
        ' Me.dgvproductoscanjes.Rows(aa).Cells(0).Value = data("seleccionar").ToString().Trim
        Me.dgvdetalle.Rows(aa).Cells(0).Value = data("IDPRODUCTO").ToString()
        Me.dgvdetalle.Rows(aa).Cells(1).Value = data("DESCRIPCION").ToString()

    Next

End Sub
```

enter event code of datagridview

```
Private Sub dgvdetalle_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dgvdetalle.KeyPress
    If Keys.Enter = 13 Then
        mostrarproductosbonus()
    End If
End Sub
```

This code, although true, works at the first enter but then when I want to look for another product with its code, it is not added, the one that is already added is repeated.

They will have some solution or help for this problem or in which I am failed.

[image]

Comment: I see no SQL at all above. Is this really related to the SQL _language_?

Comment: if you have sql only I don't put it because it's just a select productid, name from products where productid = @productid

Comment: If you need SQL assistance, show us sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) I.e. [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, even form the vb.net perspective I would say your a bit light on details.  The SQL would help.  You probably will also need to explain what DT is and where does it come from.  I would also suggest you may find you problem is a non issue using data binding and filtering/searching an in memory data collection rather than executing multiple DB queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyPress` event doesn't detect the Enter key. Use the `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event.

`Keys.Enter` will always equal `13`. That is its value in the `Enumeration`. Your `Sub` would run on every `KeyPress`. Use the value from the event args in the `KeyDown` event.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Enter")
    End If
End Sub
```

Just substitute you grid event `DataGridView1` and the `Sub` you want to call for the `MessageBox`.